# Android Jetpack DataStore "limit"

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-jetpack-datastore

As there is a Memory Exception when Shared Preferences data cross 1428.51-kb would it be the same memory constraints for the recommeded Android Jetpack DataStore?

Since DataStore uses typed objects with **protocol buffers** will there be an advantage in case of memory?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know something about that too.

Anyway hope to not be able to come back shortly with some feedback....
I'm using DataStore with the follow proto-file

```
message ResultsMessage {   
  repeated string result= 1;
  int32 countSuccess = 2;
  int32 countFail = 3;
  int32 countTotal = 4;
  repeated string history= 5; 
}
```

where strings will be the average of 20chars each and history might grow up to 10k values or more

I would like to know in advance if I should already thinking to swap to room (maybe only for history).

All apart, the best would be get more details about the generated file and his size, limit...etc etc